# test if I clicked a button before redirecting AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a div which contains ng-click to be redirected to another page to show details, but in this div I have a button (Follow) and When I click on the button I should stay on the same page 
[image]

```
<div class="panel-body" style="background-color: white;" ng-click="goToFacilitatorP(facilitator.username)">
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" data-ng-src="data:image/PNG;base64,{{facilitator.avatar}}" style="margin-top: 10px;height:120px;width:120px;" ng-show="true">
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 divtextCol">
    <h3>{{facilitator.lastname}} {{facilitator.firstname}}, {{facilitator.title}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="follow(facilitator);"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Suivre </button>
</div>
```

but here even if I click follow button, I'm redirected

```
var redirect= false;
$scope.goToFacilitatorP= function(){
console.log("function goToFacilitatorP()")  
if(redirect == false){
    $location.path('/app/facilitatorView');
}else{
    $location.path('/app/MyFacilitatorProfil');     
}
};
```

I tried to use a variable to test but it doesn't work. Can someone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the event to your function, and prevent its propagation:

```
ng-click="follow(facilitator, $event)"
```

and

```
$scope.follow = function(facilitator, $event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove that `ng-click` and re-add it 2x on the 2 containing divs underneath?

```
<div class="panel-body" style="background-color: white;">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" ng-click="goToFacilitatorP(facilitator.username)">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" data-ng-src="data:image/PNG;base64,{{facilitator.avatar}}" style="margin-top: 10px;height:120px;width:120px;" ng-show="true">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 divtextCol" ng-click="goToFacilitatorP(facilitator.username)">
        <h3>{{facilitator.lastname}} {{facilitator.firstname}}, {{facilitator.title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="follow(facilitator);"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Suivre </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Side note

I believe Bootstrap is strict about where you place columns when not working directly with form fields. An element with `.container` class directly contains one or more elements with `.row` class. An element with class `.row` directly contains one or more elements with `xx-col` class(es). You should not directly nest elements with `col` classes outside of an element with `.row` class. You can try the linter available for bootstrap to ensure you are adhering to their layout.